# WorldPay token generation in js without submitting form

Tags: javascript, laravel-4, worldpay

How to generate token without submitting the form by using javascript for world-pay payment integration in Laravel 4.2?

```
Worldpay.useForm({
    'clientKey': '{{ Config::get("app.worldpay_client_key"); }}',
    'form': form,
    'reusable': true,
    'callback': function (status, response)
    {
        document.getElementById('card_error').innerHTML = '';
        if (response.error)
        {
            Worldpay.handleError(form, document.getElementById('card_error'), response.error);
        }
        else
        {
            var token = response.token;
            Worldpay.formBuilder(form, 'input', 'hidden', 'token', token);
            form.submit();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried, if anything?

Comment: Above code I tried a lot. But I got an error or something like "WorldpayJS: f04"  in console. And the form is submitted twice. :( @archer